# Arrange SQL Query Results Differently

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2012

I'm using MS SQL Server 2012 Express

My Query is:

```
select invTypeMaterials.[typeID], invTypes.[typeName], invTypeMaterials.[quantity] from invTypeMaterials
  inner join invTypes
    on invTypeMaterials.materialTypeID = invTypes.[typeID]
```

My Results look like this:

```
typeID | typeName | quantity
18     | Blah1    | Integer
18     | Blah2    | Integer
...    | ...      | ...
36     | Blah1    | Integer
36     | Blah1    | Integer
```

I would really like my results to look like this:

```
typeID | Blah1   | Blah2   | ... | Blah7
18     | Integer | Integer | ... | Integer
...
36     | Integer | Integer | ... | Integer
```

This would be possible if I parsed the data externally but I'm hoping there is some nifty SQL statement that will do this all nice and easily for me. There is only ever Blah1 through Blah7 for types and all values of the types are integers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To google I go for a little while. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You can do this with a pivot, but part of the reason it's kind of hard to do is that, from the position relational design, this is a job that _belongs_ somewhere at the application level.

Comment: Joel, thanks for your comment I was looking for something like PIVOT (I'm still working on making it work) so that I didn't have to frame up an app or script to format / process the data. I was thinking I could try and teach myself some new SQL functionality :). Worst case I'll break down and make a script to chunk the data up. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Joel, I was able to actually perform the pivot extremely quickly in Excel which is easier than scripting it myself! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify the RDBMS that you are using. But this is basically a `PIVOT`.

MySQL:

If you are using MySQL it does not have a `PIVOT` function but it can replicated using a `CASE` statement and an aggregate function.  There are two ways to do this - either with a static version that the values are hard-coded or a dynamic version using prepared statements.

Static Version MySQL (see [SQL fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4da7f/9)):

```
select m.typeID,
  sum(case when t.typename = 'type 1' then m.quantity else 0 end) Type1,
  sum(case when t.typename = 'type 2' then m.quantity else 0 end) Type2,
  sum(case when t.typename = 'type 3' then m.quantity else 0 end) Type3
from invTypeMaterials m
inner join invTypes t
  on m.typeID = t.typeID
group by m.TypeId;
```

Dynamic version MySQL (see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4da7f/7)):

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when t.typename = ''',
      t.typename,
      ''' then m.quantity else 0 end) ',
      replace(t.typename, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from invTypeMaterials m
inner join invTypes t
  on m.typeID = t.typeID;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT m.typeID, ', @sql, ' 
                  from invTypeMaterials m
                  inner join invTypes t
                    on m.typeID = t.typeID
                   GROUP BY m.TypeId');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

SQL Server has a `PIVOT` function and you can do this either statically or dynamically.

Static version SQL Server (see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4da7f/2)):

```
select typeid,
  isnull([Type 1], 0) type1,
  isnull([Type 2], 0) type2,
  isnull([Type 3], 0) type3
from 
(
  select m.TypeId,
    m.quantity,
    t.typename
  from invTypeMaterials m
  inner join invTypes t
    on m.typeID = t.typeID
) x
pivot
(
  sum(quantity)
  for typename in ([Type 1], [Type 2], [Type 3])
) p
```

Dynamic Version SQL Server (see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4da7f/4)):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull as nvarchar(max)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(typename) 
                    from invTypes
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull 
    = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(typename) + ', 0) as '+ replace(typename, ' ', '') 
                    from invTypes
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT typeid, ' + @colsNull + ' from 
             (
                select m.TypeId,
                  m.quantity,
                  t.typename
                from invTypeMaterials m
                inner join invTypes t
                  on m.typeID = t.typeID
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(quantity)
                for typename in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. I'm back at it today so I'll let you know how it goes! I updated the question to reflect that I'm using MS SQL Server 2012.